# How to consume Web API 2 ( $http post) method in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webapi

We can't able to consume web api2 method in angular js

```
module.exports = function ($http, utils) {
    var self = this;
    self.login = function (credentials) {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        return $http.post(utils.apiUrl('admin/login'), credentials, config); 

         };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actualy touching the server, but not reading the response. Since $http returns a promise, the right way is:

```
$http.post(utils.apiUrl('admin/login', credentials, config).then(function(response) {
    return response;
});
```

Comment: actually  returning to angular  controller . this  function in service.js